# TypeORM data type Object is not supported by mysql database error (NestJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

When starting my NestJS application I am getting the following vague error:

> Data type "Object" in "MyEntity.undefined" is not supported by "mysql" database.

But `MyEntity` was deleted from my application. How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entity still exists in the build output. To solve this, remove your `dist` folder and restart your app.